# Cannot copy case class with repeated parameters

Tags: scala

Why can I not use the copy method of a case class with repeated parameters?

For example why does the last line of this code give me the error?

```
case class A(i: Int)
case class B(i: Int*)

val a = A(1).copy(i = 2)
val b1 = B(i = Seq(4, 5): _*)
val b2 = B(2, 3).copy(i = Seq(4, 5): _*)
```

> value copy is not a member of B

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to scala [specs](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/05-classes-and-objects.html#case-classes) the `copy` method is not generated, by the compiler, for case classes having a repeated parameter.

> A method named copy is implicitly added to every case class unless the class already has a member (directly defined or inherited) with that name, or the class has a repeated parameter.